# SpagoBI FirebirdSQL Metadata

Tags: firebird2.1, spagobi

I have problem creating SpagoBI model. When I try to create it, the Catalog and Schema cells are empty.

Screenshot:

[image]

Thanks,
M

```
OS & SW info:
Windows 7 x64
Java 8 Update65 x64 
Firebird 2.1.7.18553 x64 
SpagoBI Meta 5.1.0 x64 
SpagoBI 5.1.0 x64 
jaybird-full-2.2.9.jar
```

Comment: Firebird doesn't have schemas. You might want to check if installing and using the [Eclipse Data Tools Platform plugin for Firebird](https://github.com/mrotteveel/fbdtp/releases) solves your problem. Otherwise you will need to file a bug report with the vendor of this tools

Comment: Sorry, I missed to mention, FB connection i have has been made with Eclipse plugin You mentioned.

`code` Connection string:
jdbc:firebirdsql:10.0.3.10/3050:/baze/trgovina.fdb?defaultHoldable=true

Driver:
org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver

Comment: Firebird doesn't have schemas, the Firebird DTP plugin simulates a USER and SYSTEM schema because some parts of Eclipse Data Tools Platform expect that, but it looks like this wizard uses the JDBC connection directly and that doesn't report schemas at all. You might want to consider filing a bug with SpagoBI.

Comment: http://www.spagoworld.org/jira/browse/SPAGOBI-2225

I reported this problem to SpagoBI... now I'm waiting.

Thans for helping me solve the problem.